# When I add a new package I can't flutter run on M1

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, apple-m1

I have a mac M1 and it seems causing lot of problems.
When I create a project there is no error in Vscode or Xcode I can run the app normally. When I add the first package image or get for example there is no podfile created and I can run on ios the app. But when I add firebase_core, it creates a Podfile and starting from now I have only problems. In xcode there is the error "Module 'firebase_core' not found". So I do arch -x86_64 pod update ; not working, then arch -x86_64 pod install ; still the error. I don't know what to do, I just want to move on but I can't because M1 and Xcode. Maybe there is one parameter to change or one thing to install idk, help me please

Comment: Did you try to update the FFI `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

Comment: This one is not working so i'm using sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc and it still doesn't work